# Formula linear map defined by

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear map $L:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^4$ such that $$L(1,1,2)=(1,0,1,0),$$ $$L(1,2,2)=(2,0,2,0),$$ $$L(2,1,5)=(1,2,2,1).$$ How can i find the formula that linear map is defined by?

Comment: Do the vectors $(1,1,2), (1,2,2), (2,1,5)$ constitute a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$? Note that, for example, $(1,2,2)-(1,1,2) = (0,1,0)$.

Comment: Hint: $(1,2,2)-(1,1,2)=(0,1,0)$, $(1,2,2)+(2,1,5)-3(1,1,2)=(0,0,1)$

Comment: Ok, i`ve got, that (x1,x2,x3)=a(1,1,2)+b(1,2,2)+c(2,1,5) and received that a=(8x-y-3z), b=(-3x+y+z), c=(z-2x). But should i do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form the matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c|c}
b_1 & c_1 \\
b_2 & c_2 \\
b_3 & c_3 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and transform it to reduced row-echelon form. You'll get
$$
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 2 & 0\\ 
2 & 1 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 
\end{array} \right)
\to
\left( \begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & -2 & -2\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 
\end{array} \right).
$$
It then follows 
\begin{align*}
L(1,0,0) &=(0 , -4 , -2 , -2),\\
L(0,1,0) &=(1 , 0 , 1 , 0),\\
L(0,0,1) &=(0 , 2 , 1 , 1) 
\end{align*} 
(why?) and hence
$$
L(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_2,-4x_1+2x_3, -2x_1+x_2+x_3, -2x_1+x_3)
$$
for all $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbf R.$